# How to validate single element in Future[List[T]] to return Future[List[T]] or throw exception

Tags: scala, functional-programming

No need to pay attention to the purpose of the function here, it's only for demonstration:

```
def readAllByPersonOrFail(person: Person, otherPersonId: Long): Future[List[Person]] = {
  val personSiblingsFuture: Future[List[Person]] = personSiblingsDomain.readAllByPersonId(person.id)
  personSiblingsFuture.map { persons =>
    persons.find(_.id == otherPersonId) match {
      case Some(person) =>
        person.isActive match {
          case true => person
          case false => throw new IllegalArgumentException("something inactive")
        }
      case None => throw new IllegalArgumentException("something wrong ehre")
    }
  }
  personSiblingsFuture
}
```

I would like to return personSiblingsFuture above iff it validates (makes sure correct person is in the list and is active), otherwise throw the exception.  I don't think the above code is doing the right thing as it is not existing upon failure.

Comment: If the Future itself fails, your map in line 3 will never execute, and you'll just return a failed future

Comment: Exceptions are local to their own thread. Try this: `Future(throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad"))` The current thread still receives a `Future`, not the thrown exception. So there is no way `readAllByPersonOrFail()` can throw based on the evaluation of `Future` data.

Comment: Please provide [mcve], simplified examples, which compile, which are complete, so people can test. What is `personSiblingsDomain`, what is `Person`? Don't you have test cases for FutureLists, which will throw and which will not throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`scala.concurrent.Future.map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/concurrent/Future.html#map[S]((T)%20%E2%87%92%20S)(ExecutionContext):Future[S]). This creates a new future, whose value is resolved by applying a function to the successful result of this future.

Note that here you're throwing away the resulting future you just created with `.map()` too.

There are a few areas to solve your problem, though you should question more deeply the use of exceptions with `Futures`. Scala provides concepts like `Future`, `Option`, and `Try` specifically to avoid throwing exceptions and have a clearer control flow.

### Option 1, return the mapped future

In your funciton,

```
def func(...): Future[List[Person]] {
  val personSiblingsFuture = ...;
  personSiblingsFuture.map { persons =>
    ...
  }
}
// note we're not returning personSiblingsFuture,
// but the mapped result
```

When someone actually tries to get the value of the future, e.g. by using `.value`, they might see an exception intead:

```
def main() {
  val future = func(...);  // this is fine
  val my_list = future.value;  // awaits Future, might throw here
}
```

### Option 2, actually await the list and throw in the function

Returning a future that might throw is strange, it might be a bit easier if the you actually explicitly a had a function that might throw, e.g.

```
/** jsdoc describing function **/
def funcMightThrow(...): List[Person] {
  val personSiblingsFuture = ...;
  val personSiblings = personSiblingsFuture.value;

  personSiblings.find(_.id == otherPersonId) match {
    case Some(person) =>
      person.isActive match {
        case true => personSiblings
        case false => throw new IllegalArgumentException("something inactive")
      }
    case None => throw new IllegalArgumentException("something wrong ehre")
  }
}
```

### Option 3, consider making return types more explicit

```
def func(...): Future[Try[List[Person]]] {
  val personSiblingsFuture = ...;
  personSiblingsFuture.map { persons =>
    ...
    // successful case returns 'persons' (List[Person])
    // fail cases return Failure(...) instead
  }
}  // return the mapped future
```

You can also return `Try[List[Person]]` rather than a `Future[]` of that, by using `.value`, which makes `func` a blocking function.